# How can I know which security provider is handling my SSL socket?

Tags: java, security, ssl

I am trying to configure custom security provider in Java. I would like to verify that SSL connections are handled by this new security provider (connections are created by accepting new connection from server socket created by default ssl socket factory). My problem is that I cannot find out how to get security provider associated with given [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).

There is provider accessible through [`SSLContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) class, but I cannot get [`SSLContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) from [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).

Maybe there is a better way how I can verify that?

Comment: Have a look at the facilities provided by -Djava.security.debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the default `SSLSocketFactory` will use the default `SSLContext`, you can use `SSLContext.getDefault().getProvider()`.

Since `(SSL)Socket` instances are not necessarily created by a `(SSL)SocketFactory`, they provide no public API to access the factory, from which they may have been created.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will give it a try and see if it gives me expected result.